# error Subquery returned more than 1 value in sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i get this warning

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>   >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

and this my query

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwTrnLatihPerson2]
AS
SELECT 
    A.MKPersonID,
    A.RegNo, 
    A.NoFix, 
    A.Nama, 
    NIK=
        case 
            When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then (Select NIK from vwMstKaryawan Where RegNo=A.Regno)
            when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then (Select NIK from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
        End,
    Pendidikan=
        case 
            When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then (Select Pendidikan from vwMstKaryawan Where RegNo=A.Regno)
            when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then (Select Pendidikan from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
        End,
    A.JabatanID,J.Jabatan,J.SubDeptID,D.SubDeptAbbr,D.SubDeptName,D.DivisiID,
    Divisi=(Select Divisi From tblMstDivisi Where DivisiID=D.DivisiID),
    NamaDivisi=(Select NamaDivisi From tblMstDivisi Where DivisiID=D.DivisiID),
    StatusTK=
        case 
            When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then 'Karyawan'
            when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then (Select Pekerjaan from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
        End,
        A.TglMasuk,
        TglKeluar=
        case 
            When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then (Select TglKeluar from vwMstKaryawan Where RegNo=A.Regno)
            when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then (Select TglKeluar from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
        End,
        A.NotActive
FROM         
    dbo.tblTrnLatihPerson A Left Outer Join
    dbo.tblMstJabatan J On J.JabatanID=A.JabatanID LEFT Outer Join
    dbo.tblMstSubDepartment D On D.SubDeptID=J.SubDeptID
--WHERE A.NotActive <> 1
GO
```

Comment: as the message said, one of the sub query is returning more than 1 row. You need to re-look into the query and data to check that any additional condition is missed out in the subquery. A quick way to identify which sub-query is to add `TOP 1` to the select statement and then re-execute the query

Answer (score 0):

`Case` `When` expects one result only, use `SELECT TOP 1` to match that condition.

```
 When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then (Select TOP 1 NIK from vwMstKaryawan Where RegNo=A.Regno)
```

Do the same for all the rest.

Answer (score 0):

there sub query must return single value, so that just use  top keyword with 1 row
your code will be

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwTrnLatihPerson2]
AS
SELECT 
    A.MKPersonID,
    A.RegNo, 
    A.NoFix, 
    A.Nama, 
    NIK=
        case 
            When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then (Select top 1 NIK from vwMstKaryawan Where RegNo=A.Regno)
            when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then (Select top 1 NIK from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
        End,
    Pendidikan=
        case 
            When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then (Select top 1 Pendidikan from vwMstKaryawan Where RegNo=A.Regno)
            when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then (Select top 1 Pendidikan from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
        End,
    A.JabatanID,J.Jabatan,J.SubDeptID,D.SubDeptAbbr,D.SubDeptName,D.DivisiID,
    Divisi=(Select top 1 Divisi From tblMstDivisi Where DivisiID=D.DivisiID),
    NamaDivisi=(Select top 1 NamaDivisi From tblMstDivisi Where DivisiID=D.DivisiID),
    StatusTK=
        case 
            When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then 'Karyawan'
            when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then (Select top 1 Pekerjaan from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
        End,
        A.TglMasuk,
        TglKeluar=
        case 
            When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then (Select top 1 TglKeluar from vwMstKaryawan Where RegNo=A.Regno)
            when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then (Select top 1 TglKeluar from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
        End,
        A.NotActive
FROM         
    dbo.tblTrnLatihPerson A Left Outer Join
    dbo.tblMstJabatan J On J.JabatanID=A.JabatanID LEFT Outer Join
    dbo.tblMstSubDepartment D On D.SubDeptID=J.SubDeptID
--WHERE A.NotActive <> 1
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is 3 approach to resolve this error.

1. Either you add TOP 1 in you every sub-query, but it not sure to give your desired result every time
2. Second is the optimal view of your view. Join your redundant table, but you can not give top 1, so be sure only one value return for that give more and more where condition. (In isnull condition you can change 0 if your datatype is int or numeric)

   ```
   CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwTrnLatihPerson2]
   AS
   SELECT 
   A.MKPersonID,
   A.RegNo, 
   A.NoFix, 
   A.Nama, 
   NIK=
       case 
           When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then isnull( VMK.NIK , '') --(Select NIK from vwMstKaryawan Where RegNo=A.Regno)
           when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then isnull( VMB.NIK , '') --(Select NIK from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
       End,
   Pendidikan=
       case 
           When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then isnull( VMK.Pendidikan , '') --(Select Pendidikan from vwMstKaryawan Where RegNo=A.Regno)
           when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then isnull( VMB.Pendidikan , '') --(Select Pendidikan from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
       End,
   A.JabatanID,J.Jabatan,J.SubDeptID,D.SubDeptAbbr,D.SubDeptName,D.DivisiID,
   Divisi=isnull( MD.Divisi , '')--(Select Divisi From tblMstDivisi Where DivisiID=D.DivisiID),
   NamaDivisi=isnull( MD.NamaDivisi , '')--(Select NamaDivisi From tblMstDivisi Where DivisiID=D.DivisiID),
   StatusTK=
       case 
           When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then 'Karyawan'
           when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then isnull( VMB.Pekerjaan , '') --(Select Pekerjaan from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
       End,
       A.TglMasuk,
       TglKeluar=
       case 
           When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then isnull( VMK.TglKeluar , '') --(Select TglKeluar from vwMstKaryawan Where RegNo=A.Regno)
           when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then isnull( VMB.TglKeluar , '') --(Select TglKeluar from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
       End,
       A.NotActive
   FROM         
   dbo.tblTrnLatihPerson A 
   Left Outer Join dbo.tblMstJabatan J On J.JabatanID=A.JabatanID 
   LEFT Outer Join dbo.tblMstSubDepartment D On D.SubDeptID=J.SubDeptID
   --this 2 table added with left outer join AND NOTE IT SEEMS MULTIPLE VALUE YOU WILL GET THEN YOU HAVE TO ADD OTHER CONDITION TO JOIN
   LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.vwMstKaryawan VMK ON  VMK.RegNo=A.Regno
   LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.vwMstBorongan VMB ON  VMB.FixNo=A.NoFix
   LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.tblMstDivisi MD ON MD.DivisiID=D.DivisiID

   --WHERE A.NotActive <> 1
   GO
   ```
3. Use the cte which

   ```
   CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwTrnLatihPerson2]
   AS
   ; with cte as 
   (
       --GIVE ALIAS NAME TO DIFFERENTIATE THE SAME COLUMN NAME
       SELECT TOP 1 A.RegNo, A.NoFix, VMK.NIK AS ANIK, VMB.NIK AS BNIK, VMK.Pendidikan APEND, VMB.Pendidikan BPEND, --VMK.Pekerjaan, 
           VMB.Pekerjaan BPEK, VMK.TglKeluar ATGL, VMB.TglKeluar BTGL
       FROM 
       dbo.tblTrnLatihPerson A 
       Left Outer Join vwMstKaryawan VMK ON RegNo=A.Regno  --give other condition if you want WITH ORDER BY 
       Left Outer Join vwMstBorongan VMB ON FixNo=A.NoFix --give other condition if you want WITH ORDER BY 
       ),
       cte1 as
       (
       select top 1 A.Regno, D.NamaDivisi, D.Divisi from
       dbo.tblTrnLatihPerson A 
       LEFT Outer Join dbo.tblMstDivisi D On A.DivisiID=D.DivisiID --give other condition if you want WITH ORDER BY 
       )

       SELECT 
           A.MKPersonID,
           A.RegNo, 
           A.NoFix, 
           A.Nama, 
           NIK=
               case 
                   When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then CTE.ANIK --(Select NIK from vwMstKaryawan Where RegNo=A.Regno)
                   when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then CTE.BNIK --(Select NIK from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
               End,
           Pendidikan=
               case 
                   When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then CTE.APEND --(Select Pendidikan from vwMstKaryawan Where RegNo=A.Regno)
                   when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then CTE.BPEND --(Select Pendidikan from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
               End,
           A.JabatanID,J.Jabatan,J.SubDeptID,D.SubDeptAbbr,D.SubDeptName,D.DivisiID,
           Divisi=CTE1.Divisi-(Select Divisi From tblMstDivisi Where DivisiID=D.DivisiID),
           NamaDivisi= CTE1.NamaDivisi--(Select NamaDivisi From tblMstDivisi Where DivisiID=D.DivisiID),
           StatusTK=
               case 
                   When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then 'Karyawan'
                   when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then CTE.BPEK --(Select Pekerjaan from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
               End,
               A.TglMasuk,
               TglKeluar=
               case 
                   When A.RegNo<>0 And A.NoFix=0 then CTE.ATGL --(Select TglKeluar from vwMstKaryawan Where RegNo=A.Regno)
                   when A.NoFix<>0 And A.RegNo=0 then CTE.BTGL --(Select TglKeluar from vwMstBorongan Where FixNo=A.NoFix)
               End,
               A.NotActive
       FROM         
           dbo.tblTrnLatihPerson A 
           Left Outer Join dbo.tblMstJabatan J On J.JabatanID=A.JabatanID 
           LEFT Outer Join dbo.tblMstSubDepartment D On D.SubDeptID=J.SubDeptID
           LEFT Outer Join cte On cte.RegNo=A.Regno
           LEFT Outer Join cte1 On cte1.Regno=A.Regno
       --WHERE A.NotActive <> 1
       GO
   ```